# customize alert page for too many connections of apache maxclient

Tags: apache-2.2

I must make a web page that alert users , this page appair only if apache connections clients exceed specific value, for example 150 or more

Comment: That's good to know.  Did you have a question you wanted to ask?

Comment: An error page doesn't make sense in this case, as Apache has to accept the new connection to send the error. Maybe a reverse proxy just in front of your Apache can solve this problem. But there will be a problem if the reverse proxy reaches its connection limit as well. Usually the limit will be higher and will maybe solve your problem but this can be continued ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no built-in, or other good way to do this. If you really *must*  do this, this shell command will give you the number of Apache processes:

```
ps -C apache2 | wc -l
```

You could execute that in a Bash script via cron and then, for example, update Apache settings to show the page that alerts users if the value is above 150. Or you could execute it in PHP and show output accordingly.